# How do I redirect to another page after form submission in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

form

When i submit the form it redirects back to the form itself, can anyone help me?

```
    <form action="/jisajili" method="POST">
        @csrf
        <div class="card-panel z-depth-5">
            <h5 class="center red-text">Jiunge Nasi</h5>

            <div class="input-field">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="validate">
                <label>Jina lako</label>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">phone</i>
                <input type="number" name="phone" class="validate">
                <label>Nambari ya simu</label>
            </div>

             ....

            </p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Jiunge" class="btn left col s12 red">
```

Controller

```
class registration extends Controller{

     public function create(){
         return view('jisajili.jiunge');
     }

     public function store(Request $request){
         $reg = new regist;

         $reg->jina = $request->input('username');
         $reg->simuNumber = $request->input('phone');
         $reg->email = $request-> input('email');
         $reg -> password = bcrypt($request->input('password'));
         $cpassword = $request -> input('cpassword');

         $reg->save();

         $validated = $request->validate([
             'name' => 'required|unique:posts|max:10',
             'body' => 'required',
         ]);
         
         return redirect('home');
         
     }
}
```

Comment: show Controller

Comment: Show us controller code

Comment: its because validation failed here .in your form name and body inputs not there so .

Comment: What should i suppose to specify in the form action?

Comment: $reg = new regist();

Answer (score 3):

What I would do is first check for the data requirements before you add the object to the database. Also I would [add the columns of the models into the Model file](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#mass-assignment) to use the `Object::create` function with an array parameter.

I recomment to use routing in your blade file. I noticed you used `action="/route"`. What you want to do is naming your routes with `->name('route_name')` in the route files. To use them in your blade files with the global route function `route="{{ route('route_name') }}"`.

```
<?php

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('post.create');
    }

    public function store(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make(
            $request->all(),
            [
                'name' => 'required|unique:posts|max:10',
                'body' => 'required'
            ]
        );

        // Go back with errors when errors found
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            redirect()->back()->with($validator);
        }

        Post::create(
            [
                'name' => $request->get('name'),
                'body' => $request->get('body')
            ]
        );

        return redirect()
            ->to(route('home'))
            ->with('message', 'The post has been added successfully!');
    }
}
```

What you can do after this is adding custom errors into the controller or add them into your blade file. You can find more about this in [the documentation of Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors).

Answer (score 1):

it redirects you back because of validation error.

change password confirmation name from `cpassword` into `password_confirmation` as mentioned in laravel docs
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-confirmed

update your controller into:

```
public function store(Request $request){

         $validated = $request->validate([
             'username' => 'required',
             'phone' => 'required',
             'email' => 'required',
             'password' => 'required|confirmed'
         ]);

         $reg = new regist;
         $reg->jina = $request->input('username');
         $reg->simuNumber = $request->input('phone');
         $reg->email = $request-> input('email');
         $reg -> password = bcrypt($request->input('password'));

         $reg->save();
         return redirect('home');
         
     }
```

---

in your blade add the following to display validation errors:

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Best delete this before it startes to get downvotes for not being an answer. Concentrate on gettng up to 50 reps and then you can comment on any question